# simulate geographic distance between servers

Tags: networking, server, configuration, proxy, squid

I want to simulate geographic distance, so I need to add delay to each receive/transfer package.
I read that squid could help me find what I'm looking for, however, playing with its configuration haven't given me the right results.

If I'm pinging from my own PC to squid server I'm getting ~0.5 time, it's okay (would prefer ~1 time)
If I'm pinging between servers it's only ~0.255 time

I would be glad to get help finding the optimal solution for bad traffic.

---

Squid: Version 3.5.12
OS: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should ave a look at [`tc`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/tc) which is a traffic control utility interfacing the `netem` Kernel interface.

To add a general delay on outgoing packets, you may for instance do:

```
sudo tc qdisc add dev tun0 root netem delay 10ms
```

To change it, run `sudo tc qdisc change dev tun0 root netem delay 100ms`. To remove it, replace `change` with `del`.

Netem can do other tricks, such as discarding 1:n of packets, corrupting them and so forth, and can be used to emulate a wide array of network problems.

Comment: Read the manual for tc. Netem (which tc is manipulating) is a huge topic. I've used it to simulate satellite links before, and it works great - but it's a complex beast ;)